# Single word for a very gentle touch

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd like to find a single word for a very gentle touch.

Example usage:

> "As he __________ (gently touched) the petals, ..."

(may not be the best example, but I believe it brings across the point)

Comment: The verb _brush_ can have a meaning similar to what you seem to be looking for. Here is the relevant Merriam-Webster definition: "**brush** *vt* ... **3 :** to pass lightly over or across : touch gently  against in passing."

Comment: @SvenYargs Agreed! That works too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the word you're looking for is [caress](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caress): to touch or stroke lightly in a loving or endearing manner

> "As he caressed the petals, ..."

A similar option is [stroke](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stroke): to rub gently in one direction

> "As he stroked the petals, ..."